# Abstract base class with private fields

Tags: c#

So I have a variety of classes, each with a number of different properties, but I want each one to have a generic MapValue method. I've created an abstract generic base class like so:

```
public abstract class FileSectionBase<T>
{
    
    internal static IDictionary<string, Func<T, string, T>> _mappings;

    internal virtual void MapValue(string value, T model)
    {
        Func<T, string, T> function;

        if (_mappings.TryGetValue(value, out function))
        {
            function(model, value);
        }
    }
}
```

However, each class which inherits this base class needs to define a dictionary of mappings in _mappings for the inherited function to work. The function is identical for every class other than the type and the function passed back from the dictionary, so something tells me I should be able to make this work, but I can't figure out how to force the _mappings field to the inherited classes.

I can make it work using a public property, but don't really want anything other than the class itself accessing the dictionary... Ideally actually the MapValue method should be private to the inheriting class itself

Comment: *actually the MapValue method should be private to the inheriting class itself* - so, `protected` then?

Comment: Or maybe pass it as a constructor parameter to the base class?

Comment: `static` members will only have one instance per specialization of `FileSectionBase<T>`, so if two inheriting classes were to both extend `FileSectionBase<string>` for example, they would have to share the same instance of `_mappings`, which sounds like it wouldn't work for your purposes. _"Ideally actually the MapValue method should be private to the inheriting class itself"_ you can't share an implementation through inheritance and expect the method be private as well. Pick one.

Comment: in addition to what @PatrickRoberts said, having `_mappings` being static is not safe and you can have concurrency issues

Comment: So I'm still not sure I understand, it doesn't sound like I can do what I want to do? I'd have to make the mappings field public? Or make it a property instead of a field?

Comment: I figured it out - I was over complicating things, I've just put the IDictionary as a parameter of the function...